# python solver for piece wise differentiable functions

Tags: python, optimization

I have a python "blackbox" function, that is piece wisely differentiable with bounds `x>=0`. And I want to find its optimal(minimum/maximum) value.

Imagine something like `min(x^2,|x|,x^3+x^4) s.t. x>=0` (but my true function is of higher dimension `Dim(x)~=2000`). Yet I know the `subgradient` everywhere.

For example, I know exactly at every x, what is the underlying function and its gradient. But if I use the `spicy.optimize` package, using the pseudo gradient as the jacobian input, the optimizer generally terminates too early because it just gives up if it is at the "joining point of the piece wise differentiable" function and a small step does not gives a function value decrease... I think actually a robust simple gradient descent may even work better.

But I would like to know what is the best solver available for such situation.

Thank you.

Comment: This feels broad. I don't get your explanation of scipy.optimize's failure (and there are actually many very different optimizers contained). Small step? Most optimizers do use line-search to decide on the step-size. GD in it's native form is also unconstrained optimization (while yours is constrained). If a gradient-approach is to be taken, you probably want projected gradient descent. Another thing to try might be scipy's nnls. But probably everything in scipy is not fit for subgradients (but i'm not sure about that). Maybe you even want to smooth the absolute-value component.

Comment: @sascha, I tried all scipy optimizer that does not allow constraints and play with different tolerance setting. It all terminates close at the "joining point" of the piece wise functions

Comment: Because it's a local-min? That's all they would guarantee. Well... it's hard to get what you are really doing following the function above (and no code).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/295545/37212, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/89527/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49356117/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: When search gets stuck at a joining point, what does that "joining point" look like?  Is it a local minimum?  Is the local subgradient zero?  Are you on one side of the joining point where the gradient is zero?  What do the gradients of the two pieces that join there look like?  If you looked at both gradients, would one of them suggest a direction you could go to improve further (i.e., further reduce the objective function)?  I suggest you look at these values for a few specific examples, to give us more information about what is going on.